# Why does gradle initializing sometimes take very long?

Tags: java, gradle, gradlew

When I execute gradle sometimes it takes very long to "Initzialize" (up to 40 seconds).

```
PS C:\Users\Username\project> gradle build
<------------> 0% INITIALIZING [35s]
> IDLE
```

It doesn't seem to matter what goal I try to execute (`compileJava`, `test` and `build` all take this long)

If I re-run Gradle shortly after it took so long it's very quick and executes in a matter of milliseconds or seconds but if I wait longer to re-run, it again takes very long.

This happens to me in different projects and it happens with `gradlew` and also with `gradle`.

I'm on Windows 10 and I use Gradle 7.4.

Comment: `compileJava` is part of `build`, and `test` depends on `build`, so if e.g., `compileJava` is slow, the others are slow, too, as they need to run `compileJava`. Have you tried running with `--profile` to get more information? Or `--parallel` to speed things up?

Comment: @Robert `--parallel` did not result in a significant performance improvement. See this scan for performance details: https://scans.gradle.com/s/vpdk72ozzv73m/performance/build For comparison see this performance scan when I re-run gradle right after it taking a long time (as described in the question): https://scans.gradle.com/s/3rts7cpwy2o4w/performance/build As you can see there is a dramatic performance improvement.

Answer (score 14):

This is the following issue
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/17955

During initialization Gradle tries to decide if file system watching is safe to enable. On a Windows machine with network drives connected and depending on your network setup it can take a long while.

The good workaround is not to disable FSW but to enable it explicitly. This will disable the discovery process that takes a long time while keeping FSW enabled and making your builds faster.

This can be done on the command line:

```
gradlew.bat --watch-fs yourTaskName
```

Or persistently in your `gradle.properties`

```
org.gradle.vfs.watch=true
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: Use @eskatos answer.**

Explicitly enabling filesystem watch is naturally better than disabling it.

A little bit counter-intuitive and there's no hint in the documentation, but it works.

**---- old answer begins here**

TLDR: disable file system watching (if you can afford it)

```
gradlew.bat --no-watch-fs yourTaskName
```

Details:

Same problem troubled me for a month. Finally I got bored enough and after examining gradle debug output (-d key) I found that just before going into IDLE the gradle reports that:

```
[INFO] [org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner] Watching the file system is configured to be enabled if available
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Build started for file system watching' started
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.watch.registry.impl.DefaultFileWatcherRegistry] Started listening to file system change events
```

So I disabled FS watching and whoosh!

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#enabling_and_disabling_file_system_watching

Comment: Hi. That helped me with the issue. Did you find out the issue why fs is causing this? Previously everythiong worked fine

Comment: @naixx I think it's another Windows update, I don't know which one. Seems like it doesn't get along well with JDK WatchService API. I have issues in my app which I had not before, and the Gradle issue is probably another manifestation of the issue.

Comment: @tequilacat note that Gradle doesn't use the JDK WatchService API, but its own implementation in https://github.com/gradle/native-platform